# Check if two paths are pointing to the same file

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I've got a script to recursively create symlinks in my home directory to my settings directory, to keep the files under version control. I would like it to skip files which are already symlinked via a parent directory. That is, if I have these files/directories:

```
~/foo/ -> ~/settings/foo/
~/settings/foo/
~/settings/foo/bar
```

, how do I check that ~/foo/bar and ~/settings/foo/bar are the same file?

**Edit**: D'oh, another few minutes of searching revealed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script/42918#42918): `readlink -f $path`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If two files have the same deviceID and inode, they're the same file.  The `stat` command line tool makes this easy to find and this solution is POSIX shell-compliant.

```sh
if [ "$(stat -L -c %d:%i FILE1)" = "$(stat -L -c %d:%i FILE2)" ]; then
  echo "FILE1 and FILE2 refer to a single file, with one inode, on one device."
else
  echo "no match"
fi
```

The `-L` flag in each `stat` means this works for both symlinked and hardlinked files.

Comment: To follow symbolic links, you need `stat -L`.

Comment: Like @Gilles said, without the -L switch, you may get wrong results on some distributions

Comment: `stat -L -c %d:%i file` fails on macOS and FreeBSD. Those operating systems’ `stat` requires `stat -L -f %d:%i file` to return the same data.

Comment: While this syntax is POSIX-compliant, POSIX defines only the [`stat` system call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/stat.html); it does [*not*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828838) define the `stat` utility being called here.

Answer (score 25):

Many shells have a `-ef` operator for the `test` builtin (or its synonym `[`) to test whether two paths point to the *same existing file* (following symbolic links). This includes bash, dash, pdksh, ksh88, ksh93 and zsh, but not POSIX sh. In bash, ksh or zsh, you can also use `-ef` in the `[[ … ]]` conditional construct.

```
if ! [ "$1" -ef "$2" ]; then # $1 and $2 are different files
```

Comment: According to my manpage, -ef does exactly the same thing as Rich Homolka's answer.

Comment: @user13852 `-ef` has the advantage of being more portable (also slightly faster, but not so that you'd notice most of the time). For example it works on *BSD, OSX, BusyBox as well as Linux/Cygwin (GNU). It's also clearer, as it does exactly what is required. The only advantage I can see to calling `stat` is when you don't want to follow symlinks.

Comment: @user13852 And `-ef` follows symlinks, unlike Rich Homolka's original answer. `stat -L` is needed for that. (In most cases, following symlinks is more appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

For softlinks (created with `ln -s`) you can use `realpath`. This won't work for hardlinks though.