# how to make mv ignore when renaming directory with the same name

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I have a for loop on which I have directories that the `mv` command will apply the same name to its directories, other directories have different names, for example:

```
for i in {1..3};do
mv hg/ hg
done
```

Sometimes `hg/` directory will differ to something else (for example `dir/` as the loop proceeds) and the loop works when the names are different, but when the names are the same I get the error:

`mv: cannot move ‘hg/’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘hg/hg’`

I would like ignore this behavior and make `mv` just "pretend" the directories have the same name and proceed with the loop. Please note that `hg` and `dir` are just examples, the real directories have different names for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid trying to rename a directory to itself, you can protect against that with a test condition

```
src='hg'
dst='hg'
[ "$src" != "$dst" ] && mv -f "$src" "$dst"
```

If you think that one of the directory names might have a trailing slash and the other might not, then remove any trailing slash before applying the test

```
[ "${src%/}" != "${dst%/}" ] && mv -f "$src" "$dst"
```

Another more thorough but non-POSIX solution checks whether the two paths reference the same device and inode (i.e. are they the same *item* regardless of path)

```
[ ! "$src" -ef "$dst ] && mv -f "$src" "$dst"
```

Be aware that this will correctly fail when `$src` and `$dst` are visibly different but reference the same filesystem item, and therefore this test may not be suitable in many situations. For example, this will print "*Entries 'thisname' and 'another' are the same*"

```
src=thisname dst=another
touch "$src"
ln "$src" "$dst"
[ "$src" -ef "$dst" ] && printf "Entries '%s' and '%s' are the same\n" "$src" "$dst"
```

Comment: How about three trailing slashes? Or ten? Few ideas here: [*Check if two paths are pointing to the same file*](https://superuser.com/q/196572/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski there you go, but notice it may not be suitable for the OP's situation